# 2014 Mazda 3 Audio with Android phone through USB

Tags: mazda, audio, mazda-3

For reference, I have [this audio unit](http://pictures.dealer.com/j/jimellismazdamarietta/1855/949bdba5ca5ec80ac78795909d2b76f7x.jpg).

[image]

I used to just plug in my iPhone and press the 'Media' button to get songs to play, but it doesn't seem to work with an Android phone. I just get a 'Check USB' message. Is playing songs from my Android phone through Spotify through a USB cable possible with the stock unit?

What options do I have? Are there third-party units that I can buy to replace the stock one that play nicely with my Android phone?

Thanks

Comment: Does [this video](https://youtu.be/vKM7OM8T7z0) help you with connecting your Bluetooth? Right at the beginning she describes (briefly) the steps to getting your Bluetooth to pair.

Comment: @Paulster2 Ah, I should've edited my question. I was indeed able to connect via Bluetooth right after I posted this. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Then is this question actually moot? Considering where the unit is mounted, I'm doubting there is *anything* aftermarket which will take its place.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put no.

Apple has kept one thing going from the original inception of the IPhone. It has dedicated audio circuits plumbed out to the charging connector. With the older IPhone this was very obvious because of the large connector with many pins. With the newer lightning connector the audio paths are still there (although they are now digital). It is this consistency that has allowed so many different devices to support the IPhone.

Android does not have such humble beginnings. Because Google does not have control of the hardware that Android goes on there is no guarantee that audio is plumbed out though to the charging connector (what ever it may be). Because of this very few devices actually support audio though the charging port on Android.